Не отображается кастомная метка в AndroidView
При вызове setIcon иконка исчезает полностью.
Получается отобразить только исходную иконку с текстом, если не вызывать geometry = Point() и setIcon.
    AndroidView(factory = { MapView(it) }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        mapView = it
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = "loadMapView") {
        snapshotFlow { mapView }.collect {
            it?.let {
                val map = it.mapWindow.map
                map.move(
                    CameraPosition(...)
                )
                val marker = map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(Point(55.791090, 49.121310))
                    .apply {
                        setText("sample")
                        setIconStyle(
                            IconStyle().apply {
                                anchor = PointF(0.5f, 1.0f)
                                scale = 2f
                                zIndex = 10f
                            }
                        )
                        setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(context, R.drawable.map_pin))
                    }

                MapKitFactory.initialize(context)
                MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
                it.onStart()
            }
        }
    }


Я ничего не знаю про yandexmapkit, но разве всякие там initialize и onStart не должны выполнять как то единожды, а не на каждый collect?

Пожалуйста, прикрепите к вопросу или пришлите в поддержку на maps-api@support.yandex.ru полный пример собранного кода для проверки. Вы можете выложить его проектом на GitHub, прикрепить к переписке в архиве или загрузить на Яндекс Диск и указать ссылку.
